# IIS URL Rewrite not appending query string

Tags: html, windows, iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a an IIS website `http://localhost:4200` under which I have two files: `url.asp` and `url.html`.

The files look like so:

url.asp:

```
<h2>Query Strings: <%= Request.QueryString %></h2>
```

url.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h2 id="location" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('location').innerText = `Query Strings: ${location.search}`;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Essentially both files print the query strings in the URL.

I also have an IIS virtual directory `http://localhost/abc` where I have a single web.config file which contains only URL rewrite rules and looks like so:

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="InboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="z(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" 
                            url="http://localhost:4200/url.asp?p={R:1}"
                            appendQueryString="true"
                            logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="InboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" 
                            url="http://localhost:4200/url.html?p={R:1}"
                            appendQueryString="true"
                            logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Question**

When I hit `http://localhost/abc/z123` I get:

> Query Strings: p=123

This is what I am expecting. This request gets redirected (rewritten) to the `url.asp` file.

However, when I hit `http://localhost/abc/123` I get:

> Query Strings:

No query string is printed in this case. This request gets redirected (rewritten) to the `url.html` file.

So, via IIS URL rewrite, if I pass a query string to an asp file it gets the query string. But when I pass the query string to an HTML file it does not get it.

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in InboundRule2, your {R:1} is *http://localhost/abc/123*:

[image]

You need to modify your rewrite rules as follows:

[image]

The query string at this time should be {R:2}:

```
           <rule name="InboundRule2">
                <match url="(abc)/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:4200/url.html?p={R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is because URL.html will get the query string of the URL in the current page. If you visit http://localhost/abc/123, url.html will get the query string from this URL, but the query string does not exist in this URL, so you will see that Query Strings is empty.

You can try to add the query string after http://localhost/abc/123:

[image]

You can use redirect to solve this problem.

Comment: I am sorry I do not think I was able to make my problem understood. The web.config that has the URL rewrite rules is under an IIS virtual directory called ```abc``` (```http://localhost/abc```), not under ```http://localhost```.

The URL rewrite works fine for both rules 'InboundRule1' and 'InboundRule2', one redirecting to an ".asp" file while the other redirecting to an ".html" file.

The problem is, the ".asp" file receives the query strings I am passing via the URL rewrite rule but the ".html" file does not.

I am not sure how to explain this and looking for an explanation.

Comment: Do you still have this problem when you delete the InboundRule1?

Comment: Yes. I do. The "InboundRule1" is just to demonstrate that the query strings are passed under certain circumstances. My problem is actually with the "InboundRule2".